# Cannot access iFrame as it has a transparent PNG on top of it

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, youtube-iframe-api

Have embedded a you tube iFrame in my webpage. To make it look more appealing I placed a a transparent png image (photoframe) on top of it.

Now I cannot click on the iFrame as it is overlay by another element.

How do I access the iFrame?

```
 <div class="Video_Block">
 <iframe width="948" height="632" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/36UQCZEsY9g?autoplay=1&mute=1" title="Offical trailer of The Time Machine - A Rod Taylor Movie -1960" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 <img class="videoFrame" src="images/author/Video Frame.png" alt="Video Frame">
 <p class="Video_Title">The Time Machine</p>
 </div>

.Video_Block{
      /*border: 1px solid blue;*/
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
      position: relative;
}

.Video_Block .videoFrame{
      position: absolute;
      width: 90%;
      height: 90%;
      left: 10px;
      top: 10px;
 }

 .Video_Block iframe {
      background-color: black;
      position: absolute;
      left: 35px;
      top: 40px;
      height: 175px;
      width: 195px;
      object-fit: contain;
      transition: border-radius 0.5s;
  [![Photo frame on top of the youtube-iFrame][1]][1]}
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks so much for the reply. 'pointer-events: none'. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach would be to *surround* the iframe in an element and style the container, if at all possible, like:

```
<div class="Video_Block">
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe width="948" height="632" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/36UQCZEsY9g?autoplay=1&mute=1" title="Offical trailer of The Time Machine - A Rod Taylor Movie -1960" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   <p class="Video_Title">The Time Machine</p>
</div>
```

Then apply CSS rules to `video-container` as desired (with a border or whatever else) - hard to say exactly without knowing what the `Video Frame.png` is).

If there's no way to replicate the effect you need in CSS alone, you can keep click events from registering on the image by giving [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to the `<img>`.

```
.Video_Block .videoFrame {
  pointer-events: none;
  ...
```

This way, if the image is overlapping the iframe, clicks will bypass the image and go directly to the iframe.